# Accurately computing $\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^j}{j!} \zeta(j)$

Tags: numerics, special-functions, summation, precision-and-accuracy

I'm doing a sanity check of the following equation:
$$\sum_{j=2}^\infty \frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\zeta(j) \approx x(\log x + 2 \gamma -1)$$

Naive comparison of the two shows a bad match but I suspect one of the graphs is incorrect.

1. Why isn't there a warning?
2. How do I compute this sum correctly?

```
katsurda[x_] := NSum[(-x)^j/j!  Zeta[j], {j, 2, Infinity}];
katsurdaApprox[x_] := x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) - Zeta[0];
plot1 = DiscretePlot[katsurda[x], {x, 0, 40, 2}];
plot2 = Plot[katsurdaApprox[x], {x, 0, 40}];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

3. **meta** How do I avoid being mislead by incorrect numeric results? Would using `NIntegrate` instead of `NSum` give better guarantees? My usual approach of a avoiding machine precision, checking `Precision` of the answer and minding warnings fails in the example below

```
katsurda[x_] := 
  NSum[(-x)^j/j! Zeta[j], {j, 2, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 32, 
   NSumTerms -> 2.5 x];
katsurdaApprox[x_] := x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) - Zeta[0];
Print["Precision: ", Precision@katsurda[100]] (* 13.9729 *)
Print["Discrepancy: ", katsurda[100] - katsurdaApprox[100]] (* 94.65088290385, but should be <1 *)
```

**Background:**  the expression comes from "Power series with the Riemann zeta-function in the coefficients" by Katsurada M ([paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/proceedings-of-the-japan-academy-series-a-mathematical-sciences/volume-72/issue-3/Power-series-with-the-Riemann-zeta-function-in-the-coefficients/10.3792/pjaa.72.61.pdf))

Comment: BTW, I don't know a general answer for question 3 for `NSum`. I have a good idea how many of the methods of `NIntegrate` and `NDSolve` work. One test is to raise `WorkingPrecision` and `PrecisionGoal`, and perhaps `AccuracyGoal`, and see if the result is stable. That hasn't always been reliable for `NSum` for me. The `Precision` of an answer in *Mma* usually indicates only the effect of round-off. It is not good indicator of convergence/nonconvergence. For the sum at hand, since it is alternating and eventually decreasing in magnitude, `Method -> "AlternatingSigns"`, should be reliable.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is the internal heuristics governed by `NSumTerms`. I tried to use NIntegrate by splitting series into positive/negative parts and treating each as Riemann sum, but this approximation turned out to be bad for large x https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-katsurda-split.nb

Comment: I did something similar, but using successive pairs to get a non-alternating series. `NIntegrate` couldn't handle the it.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau you guys should use this to debug `NSumTerms->Automatic` :)

Answer (score 9):

The sum is alternating, so you might need extra precision and `NSumTerms`:

```
katsurda[x_] := 
  NSum[(-x)^j/j! Zeta[j], {j, 2, Infinity}, WorkingPrecision -> 16, 
   NSumTerms -> Max[15, 2 x]];
katsurdaApprox[x_] := x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) - Zeta[0];
plot1 = DiscretePlot[katsurda[x], {x, 0, 40, 2}];
plot2 = Plot[katsurdaApprox[x], {x, 0, 40}];
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Note: There is a warning, but it's suppressed by the plotter:

```
Block[{x = 30},
 NSum[(-x)^j/j! Zeta[j], {j, 2, Infinity}]
 ]
```

> NumericalMath`NSequenceLimit::seqlim: The general form of the sequence could not be determined, and the result may be incorrect.

```
(*  126.442  *)
```

**Update:**

Here's a way to estimate the needed precision by estimating the largest term in the series. The method `"AlternatingSigns"` is (or should be) a reliable method for the sum, provided the working precision is high enough.

```
katsurda[x_] := NSum[(-x)^j/j! Zeta[j], {j, 2, Infinity},
   WorkingPrecision -> 
    16 + 
     FindMaxValue[{(j0*Log[x] - LogGamma[1 + j0])/Log[10], 
       j0 > 1}, {j0, x}], NSumTerms -> Max[15, 4 + 2 x],
   Method -> "AlternatingSigns"];
katsurdaApprox[x_] := x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) - Zeta[0];
plot1 = DiscretePlot[katsurda[x], {x, Round[1.5^Range[10, 17]]}];
plot2 = Plot[katsurdaApprox[x], {x, 50, 1000}];
Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

**Update 2:**

After some playing, we can see that the maximum for large `x` is around `j == x`, and `Method -> "AlternatingSigns"` adjusts the number of terms needed automatically. So `WorkingPrecision -> 16 + x` ensures a sufficient precision for `x >= 0`. Thus here's a simplified code:

```
katsurda[x_] := 
 NSum[(-x)^j/j! Zeta[j], {j, 2, Infinity}, 
  Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 16 + x]
```

Comment: Interesting! BTW, the number $16$ seems special here, how did you come up with it? If I use `WorkingPrecision -> 32` then I get a big discrepancy and no warning in `katsurda[100] - katsurdaApprox[100]`

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov I'm just figuring out that `2 x` for `NSumTerms` is not large enough for large `x`.  I'm not sure how to determine the "right" number. At least yet :) -- Sorry, `2.5 x` doesn't really work for `x = 100`.

Comment: Using `NSumTerms -> 2.5 x` terms and `WorkingPrecision->32` tells me that this approximation is off by 94.65 for $x=100$. There's no warning and 94.65 answer has 13.97 digits of precision. But I think this answer is wrong....lack of warning bothers me a bit...

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Yes, I had to use `WorkingPrecision -> 64` Or `128`?  Clearly both `NSumTerms` and `WorkingPrecision` have to go up with `x`. Also `Method -> "AlternatingSigns"`, which it does not default to, seems to work better (and maybe faster).

Answer (score 2):

Using the $d$-type [Weniger transformation](https://doi.org/10.1016/0167-7977(89)90011-7), as implemented in [`ResourceFunction["WenigerSum"]`](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/WenigerSum/), we get the following:

```
Plot[{ResourceFunction["WenigerSum"][(-x)^j Zeta[j]/j!, {j, 2, ∞},
                                     "ExtraTerms" -> 25, "Type" -> "D", WorkingPrecision -> 20], 
      x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) - Zeta[0]} // Evaluate, {x, 0, 45}, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image: Weniger sum vs. asymptotic approximation]

```
Plot[ResourceFunction["WenigerSum"][(-x)^j Zeta[j]/j!, {j, 2, ∞},
                                    "ExtraTerms" -> 25, "Type" -> "D", WorkingPrecision -> 20] -
     (x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) - Zeta[0]) // Evaluate, {x, 0, 45},
     PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 25]
```

[image: residual]

One would need to play around with the `"ExtraTerms"` and `"Terms"` settings for this function (e.g. try the combination `"Terms" -> 0, "ExtraTerms" -> 35`), and one has to use high precision as well to stave off the looming threat of catastrophic cancellation, especially for large $x$. I have chosen the $d$-type transformation since the original series is alternating (as recommended by Weniger), but the $t$-type (`"Type" -> "T"`) can be used on such series as well. I invite you to do your own experiments.

Answer (score 1):

Turn the sum around to make it non-alternating:

$$
\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\zeta(j) =
\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^j}\right) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\sum_{j=2}^{\infty}\frac{(-x)^j}{j!}\frac{1}{n^j}\right) =
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(e^{-x/n}-1+\frac{x}{n}\right)
$$

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := NSum[E^(-x/n) - 1 + x/n, {n, ∞}, Method -> "EulerMaclaurin"]
g[x_] = x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) + 1/2;

Plot[f[x] - g[x], {x, 0, 1000}]
```

[image]

The remaining difference between the expressions is due to numerical inaccuracies and can be fixed by increasing the [`WorkingPrecision`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WorkingPrecision.html).

Comment: It might be a good idea to use ``Internal`Expm1[]`` here to guard against cancellation: ``NSum[Internal`Expm1[-x/n] + x/n, {n, 1, ∞}, Method -> "EulerMaclaurin"]``

Answer (score 0):

Another way using:

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty } \left(\exp \left(-\frac{x}{n}\right)-1+\frac{x}{n}\right)=\int_0^{\infty } \left(\frac{x}{-1+e^z}-\frac{\sqrt{x}
   J_1\left(2 \sqrt{x} \sqrt{z}\right)}{\left(-1+e^z\right) \sqrt{z}}\right) \, dz$$

```
 f[x_] := NIntegrate[InverseLaplaceTransform[Exp[-x/n] - 1 + x/n, n, z]/(Exp[z] - 1), {z, 0, Infinity}, Method -> "LocalAdaptive"];

 fApprox[x_] := x (Log[x] + 2 EulerGamma - 1) + 1/2;
 plot1 = DiscretePlot[f[x], {x, Round[(E - 1)^Range[10, 17]]}];
 plot2 = Plot[fApprox[x], {x, 50, 10000}];
 Show[plot1, plot2, PlotRange -> All]
 DiscretePlot[f[x] - fApprox[x], {x, Round[(E - 1)^Range[10, 17]]}]
```